# Link library developed in old Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

I am using Visual Studio 2010 but has received an external library developed for Visual Studio 2008. If I try to link the library into my program, I get the following error:

```
Activation context generation failed for "Tutorial.exe". 
Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",
publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win3
```

Is there any way that I can link the library anyway?

Comment: The external library that is developed for VS2008 should ideally be used with projects in VS2008. This is because of dependencies on the MSVC Runtime library. Perhaps you should try to find the same library that was compiled with VS2010 instead or get the source code and compile it yourself?

Comment: I've talked to the company that develops the library, and they're doing an update that they expect to release in a month. But I just want to get it to work until then.

Comment: I've linked to VC4.2 libraries using VC9 (2008) before... they were dynamic libraries though.

Comment: Is the external library a dll or static library? Was the external library compiled with static or dynamic linkage to VS2008 runtime library?

Comment: @Dennis : Maybe the VC4.2 libraries that you were using was compiled with the option of static linkage to VC4.2 runtime library and therefore the libraries already include the runtime library itself?

Comment: It is not a linker error, it is a *runtime* error.  You don't have the VS2008 version of the CRT dlls installed on the machine.  That's fixable by just downloading the installer from Microsoft, but having *two* versions of the CRT in use in one program is very unhealthy.  Ask the vendor for an update, a simple rebuild is all it takes.

Comment: Oh, and you need the debug version of the CRT.  Can't download that from Microsoft.  Linking the release version of that library is your only recourse.  Ask for the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it seems that you are linking the debug version of the external library that requires the debug version of VS2008 runtime library. Note that Microsoft do not distribute debug versions of their VC runtime library so either you have to

a) Install VS2008 itself so that it installs both debug and release version of VS2008 runtime library into the system.

OR

b) Install VS2008 re-distributable package and use only the release version of the external library in your project.